# Magento multi store on different domains in subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

How do you set up Magento multi-store on different URLs that are in subdomains?
Our main sites are live sites so we can't currently use the top domain and we want to use a sandbox environment before we switch the development site to live.

Example.

sandbox.SiteA.com

sandbox.SiteB.com

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195/different-storeviews-or-websites-in-subfolders review this post for details

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's a bad idea to put DEV sites in subfolders, if you forget how to configure it right, they might be indexed by google and this might break your SEO ranking and even points customers to DEV sites. I recommend using

- sandbox.siteA.com
- sandbox.siteB.com

for dev sites and secure them with http basic authentication.

You need to create a uinque magento installation in a separate folder on the server and setup `base_url` and `secure_base_url` to point to correct URL.

If you want to go with subfolders (which I don't recommend) check your magento server configuration if a

> RewriteBase

directive is set to point to a folder. For example: for apache server if you want to use a subfolder make sure in your **.htaccess** file you have

```
RewriteBase /devfolder/
```

for http://www.siteA.com/devfolder/

If it's a multistore setup remember to setup Env. Variables in your **.htaccess** file so correct store is lunched when site is accessed:

```
SetEnvIf Host devsite\.siteA\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=sitea
SetEnvIf Host devsite\.siteA\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host devsite\.siteB\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=siteb
SetEnvIf Host devsite\.siteB\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Comment: Yes i meant sub-domains. like your examples: sandbox.siteA.com
This is the email we got from the server support:

Everything is setup properly according to the tutorial. Please note that the document root of the parked domain (sandbox.siteB.com) is the same as the document root of the primary domain in this case this is SiteA.com.

In other words the parked domain does not even reaches the folder of the sandbox website at all it reaches the primary application and this is why it does not work.